# Android library media_jni not found

Tags: android, media, android-source

I'm trying to replicate this class called MediaMetadataRetriever in my own android project. You can see the class here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.java

In line # 40 you can see: `System.loadLibrary("media_jni");`

How do I get that library? My logcat shows this:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library media_jni not found

Answer (score 0):

This is a JNI class, which is created in C/C++ and included as a SO in your app. The class is loaded during runtime.

Look here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/jni

Comment: Yeah I reached there but what should I do, import the related .cpp in my own project ? I had a look at the .cpp which is related to me it has a lot of dependencies. Looks complicated ?